How to correctly plot an RCS curve?
I plan to fit an RCS curve, and my code is as follows:
dd <- datadist(dt)
options(datadist = "dd")

surv <- Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(age, 4)
fit <- cph(surv, data = dt, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)

ggplot(Predict(fit, age, fun = exp, ref.zero = TRUE))

Is this fitting correct? I found some R packages and checked the source code, and I noticed that in the Surv function, the status is set to 1: Surv(time, status == 1) ~ rcs(age, 4). What is the purpose of doing this? Do I also need to modify my code to Surv(time, status == 1) ~ rcs(age, 4)?
